# How to select two rows from multiple rows of a column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data like this

```
ID     | Race    | start | duration
-------|---------| ------| ---------
234    | 1010    | turtle| 100
235    | 1010    | turtle| 101
236    | 1010    | turtle| 99
237    | 1010    | rabbit| 199
238    | 1010    | rabbit| 201
239    | 1010    | rabbit| 85
240    | 9898    | rabbit| 185
241    | 9898    | rabbit| 205
242    | 9898    | rabbit| 505
243    | 9898    | turtle| 155
244    | 9898    | turtle| 104
```

from this I would like to select:

- one `turtle` and one `rabbit` from each group
- the one has to have the least duration in its group

Example:

Based on above data, the results should be:

```
ID     | Race    | start | duration
-------|---------| ------| ---------
236    | 1010    | turtle| 99
239    | 1010    | rabbit| 85
240    | 9898    | rabbit| 185
244    | 9898    | turtle| 104
```

What I've done:

```
w = Window().partitionBy("race").orderBy(col("duration").desc())
(df
  .withColumn("rn", rowNumber().over(w))
  .where(col("rn") == 1)
  .select("race", "duration")).show()
```

However, this groups the data and I'm not getting the desired results.

Comment: `partitionBy("race", "start")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you should use rank instead of rownumber and make the window of "race" and "start" columns here is the code snippet which will solve your problem:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[234,1010,'turtle', 100],
                        [235,1010,'turtle', 101],
                        [236,1010,'turtle', 99],
                        [237,1010,'rabbit', 199],
                        [238,1010,'rabbit', 201],
                        [239,1010,'rabbit', 85],
                        [240,9898,'rabbit', 185],
                        [241,9898,'rabbit', 205],
                        [242,9898,'rabbit', 505],
                        [243,9898,'turtle', 155],
                        [244,9898,'turtle', 104]
                       ], ['id', 'race', 'start', 'duration'])
w1 = Window().partitionBy("race", "start").orderBy(F.col("duration"))
df.withColumn("rn", F.rank().over(w1)).where(F.col("rn") == 1).select("id", "race", "start", "duration").show()
```